# Minimal Morse link-derived presentation of a rational knot

Tags: knot-theory

[image]

Copied from the Knot Atlas and annotated. As you see, $7_2$ needs $4$ braid strands (any rational knot needs at most 4), but if we cheat and define "closure" differently, we could say "The knot $7_2$ can be mapped to a $2$-tangle, which can be obtained by a Temperley-Lieb closure (of the lowest $2$ strands) of a braid which only needs $3$ strands".

My question: I think *any* rational knot (or link) needs only $3$ strands. (This even is a cool possibility to assign a binary number to it.) Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you only need three strands. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833063/2-bridge-knot-with-straightened-strand

Comment: THX...although this cute trick doesn't prove a sharper version (which I would need): for rational knots, you only need overcrossing on strand 1/2 and undercrossings on 2/3.

Comment: Make sure to update your question that that's what you're asking about. I wouldn't be surprised if that version of the result is in Conway, *An enumeration of knots and links and some of their algebraic properties*.

Comment: I rather ask a new question if (I also would be surprised if Conway didn't consider it) I don't find it there :-)

Comment: To clarify, it's known you can always put it into this form due to the fact that the braid can be read off from a continued fraction representation of a ratio for the rational knot. I think that might be the original source, but you can certainly find it elsewhere.